# data not uploading in mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am converting the Url Data to binary here

```
bpdfdata = dataUrlToBinary(pdfData);
function dataUrlToBinary(dataUrl) {
            
            const base64Part = dataUrl.split(',')[1];

            const binaryData = atob(base64Part);

            const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(binaryData.length);
            for (let i = 0; i < binaryData.length; i++) {
                uint8Array[i] = binaryData.charCodeAt(i);
            }

            return uint8Array;
        }
```

And then Sending to upload_pdf.php using this code

```
function sendToServer(pdfData) {
            fetch('upload_pdf.php', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: pdfData, 
                })
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log('Response Status:', response.status);
                    console.log('Response Status Text:', response.statusText);

                    if (response.ok) {
                        console.log('PDF uploaded successfully.');
                    } else {
                        console.error('Failed to upload PDF.');
                    }
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error('Error uploading PDF:', error);
                });
        }
```

[This the Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YikyS.png) 
[But in database Nothing is storing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbUDC.png)

This is my code for uploading the data

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    $pdfBinaryData = file_get_contents("php://input");


    $host = 'localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $port = 3307;
    $dbname = 'Shareimg_3';


    $conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $dbname, $port);


    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die('Connection failed: ' . $conn->connect_error);
    }


    $sql = "INSERT INTO pdf (pdf_data) VALUES (?) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin";


    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('b', $pdfBinaryData);

    if ($stmt) {

        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            echo 'PDF uploaded and inserted into the database successfully.';
        } else {
            echo 'Error inserting PDF into the database: ' . $stmt->error;
        }


        $stmt->close();
    } else {
        echo 'Error preparing SQL statement: ' . $conn->error;
    }


    $conn->close();
} else {

    http_response_code(400);
    echo 'Invalid request.';
}
?>
```

Comment: What's in the body of the response? Maybe `Error inserting PDF into the database: (some error here)`? ^^ (your code returns status 200 either way, only the body is different in case of error)

Comment: You need to take some debugging steps. start from saving the file locally. this way you can make sure that JS works right and actually uploads the file in the server.